# Regex to match nth occurrence and return part of the next line of a string

Tags: regex

I am using Zapier to extract names from the body of an email and I need to use a Regex to return nth occurrence of a name in the string for each step of the Zap.

Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tbVSmD/2/) I am working with

For example for the 2nd part of the Zap I want to return 'John Morlu, CPA, CFE, CIA, CMA, CGFM, PMP, CISA' from the string.

The names will be different each time the Regex is run, so the Regex must return the data that sits between each instance of '.....................................' and ' ('

So far I have:

(?mis)\A(?:.*?^.[ ]+){2}(.*?)(?=[ ]*()

but I am stuck

How do I adjust the code to return the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd name in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the regex to specifically select the n-th match? Or can you select the n-th match from a set of matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the n-th match only (instead of a list of matches to select the n-th from), this gets the first match:

```
(?:\.{37}\s+.+?\(.*?){0}\.{37}\s+(.+?)\(
```

This gets the second:

```
(?:\.{37}\s+.+?\(.*?){1}\.{37}\s+(.+?)\(
```

And the third:

```
(?:\.{37}\s+.+?\(.*?){2}\.{37}\s+(.+?)\(
```

Etc.

Basic explanation:
- the first half, starting with `?:` is a non-capturing group; it needs to be matched, but it's not part of what's captured.
- the `{x}` behind it causes it to be matched `x` times, so to match the first, that's 0 times, to match the second 1 times, etc.
- the rest of the expression matches the same again, but now it's group 1 you're after.

To just get a list to select from:

```
\.{37}\s+(.+?)\(
```

Comment: That's awesome thank you so much! I just added [ ] at the end to remove the final space: (?:\.{37}\s+.+?\(.*?){0}\.{37}\s+(.+?)[ ]\(  Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I tried the second match using {1} and it didn't seem to work? Do you know why? Here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/tbVSmD/3

Comment: You need to set the regex engine options so that "Single Line | dot matches newline", or `/gms`. See here https://regex101.com/r/tbVSmD/4

Comment: Thank you that makes sense - unfortunately because I am using Zapier, there is no way to change the Regex engine options - do you know if there is a way to do this without changing the engine options?

Comment: I figured it out - I needed to add (?mis) so the final version was (?mis)(?:\.{37}\s+.+?\(.*?){1}\.{37}\s+(.+?)[ ]\( Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the information of interest for the 3<sup>rd</sup> person on the list you can use the following regex:

```
(?:(?:^.*\s)*?\.{20}\.*\s+){3}\K.[^\)]*\)
```

As the regex engine was not specified, I used PCRE (PHP).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yWVUvy/2/)

I assumed the dividing lines of periods (37 per line in the example) contain at least 20 periods.

The regex performs the following operations.

```
(?:             # begin a non-cap group
  (?:^.*\s)     # match entire line, incl. newline, in a non-cap group
  *?            # execute the non-cap group 0+ times, non-greedily
  \.{20}\.*\s+  # match entire line of 20+ periods, incl.
                #   the newline, followed by 0+ empty lines
)               # end the non-cap group
{3}             # execute the non-cap group 3 times
\K              # forget everything matched so far
[^\)]*          # match 0+ chars other than ')'
\)              # match ')'
```